# How to run a command in bash script from another directory

Tags: linux, bash, sh

So I'm trying to do some simple directory traversal and run some scripts.

The plan was to pass 2 variables to my code with `PID=123 DIRNAME=Lalaland bash magic.sh`

The script is

```
echo "SCRIPT BEGIN"
PPWD=$(pwd)
BRC="/../"
echo $PPWD
echo $BRC
echo ${PPWD}${BRC}
cd ${PPWD}${BRC}
git pull
cd ../Web
nodejs server.js
echo "SCRIPT END"
```

`echo ${PPWD}${BRC}` returns `/../e/git/Gitorade`.

`git status` does not run.

`cd ../Web` is also broken somehow.

I get this at the end:

```
SCRIPT BEGIN
/home/git/Gitorade
/../
/../e/git/Gitorade
: No such file or directorye/git/Gitorade
' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        status
: No such file or directoryeb
SCRIPT END
```

I understand that I have probably made some terrible syntax errors but I have spent some embarassing time debugging this and I have good knowledge of programming languages but none of shell ones. Is there maybe some good tutorial for this or some cheat sheet because I am hopeless...

EDIT:

I have also tried:

```
echo "SCRIPT BEGIN"
PPWD=$(pwd)
PPWD=${PPWD%$'\r'}
BRC="/../"
echo $PPWD
echo $BRC
echo "${PPWD} ${BRC}"
echo ${PPWD}${BRC}
echo $PPWD "asd"
echo $PPWD "ASD" $PPWD
echo $PPWD$PPWD
echo $BRC$BRC
echo ${PPWD}${PPWD}
cd ${PPWD}${BRC}
git status
cd ./../Gitorade
```

which resulted in

```
SCRIPT BEGIN
/home/git/Gitorade
/../
 /..//git/Gitorade
/../e/git/Gitorade
 asde/git/Gitorade
 ASD /home/git/Gitorade
/home/git/Gitorade
/../
/home/git/Gitorade
```

Comment: Also, why can't I use LS command in my script?

Comment: The source and the output don't match. if `PPWD` is `/home/git/Gitorade` and `BRC` is `/../`, the concatenation of both cannot be `/../e/git/Gitorade`

Comment: DOS line endings explain why you get `/../e/git/Gitorade` instead of `/home/git/Gitorade/../`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGutiérrez Yes, it can, precisely because of the carriage return found at the end of the value of `PPWD`.

Comment: How would I remove the CR? (any oneliners?)

Comment: I have tried $PPWD=${PPWD#\r} but i suppose its not it

Comment: It's `PPWD=${PPWD%$'\r'}`; `%`, not `#`, removes a suffix, and a carriage return is specified by `$'\r`. `\r` evaluate to the letter `r` itself.

Comment: Im afraid it did not change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92910/discussion-between-dominikditoivosevic-and-chepner).